# Bind DatePicker to List of Dates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, charts

Probably irrelevant, but I have an Infragistics XamDataChart that has a CategoryXAxis of Dates.  I have managed to bind a date picker to the range of dates available in the chart, but I really need to bind to the specific list of dates plotted on the chart.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="statsDatePicker" DisplayDateStart="{Binding Path=ActualMinimumValue.Date, ElementName=xAxisPath, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding ElementName=xAxisPath, Path=ActualMaximumValue.Date, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />
```

I have found that you can provide a list of blackout dates, but how does one take a range of dates I have and turn it into a range of dates I don't?  Or, is there a way to provide the date picker the dates I have instead of the dates I don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
DateTime end = DateTime.MaxValue;
DateTime start = DateTime.MinValue;
List<DateTime> datesIHave= new List<DateTime>();
datesIHave.Add(DateTime.Now);
List<DateTime> allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days).Select(offset => start.AddDays(offset)).ToList();
List<DateTime> blackoutDates = (from a in allDates 
                                where !datesIHave.Contains(a)
                                select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Any idea if this is possible with xaml and data binding?

Comment: This code is my attempt at answering "I have found that you can provide a list of blackout dates, but how to take a range of dates I have and turn it into a range of dates I don't?" When you set the datesIHave variable to the dates that you want to be made available, the code in my answer should give you all other dates, and you can provide the blackout dates to your XamDataChart. That's the idea I had, anyway.

Comment: Just edited because I noticed I had the end and start dates switched, but at the same time, if you have a date range already set to your datepicker that is smaller than the min and max value, you should set the end and start variables accordingly, so it will run as fast as possible.